# Hyper-V vSwitch IP using powershell

Tags: hyper-v

I have  vSwitch that is set to **not** `Allow management operating system to share this network adaptor`

I would like to know what the IP address is configure against the vSwitch, can anyone tell me how i can get this information via powershell?

Answer (score 1):

The Hyper-V Virtual Switch doesn't get an IP Address. VMs and the Host OS that connect to the virtual switches do get IP Addresses. When a VM is connected to a switch and powered on a virtual port is created for the VM (the same for the host if it is sharing the Virtual Switch). You can query the virtual port and find information about it including IP information using the following PowerShell command: **Get-VMNetworkAdapter**

[image: Get-VMNetworkAdapter]

Where **Server1** is the name of my VM. you can also use:

**Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName Server1 | fl**

to get even more info and display it better.

Hope This Helps.

Mike.